# Switch statements refactor

Tags: java

I'm looking for advise on how best to refactor a rather large legacy method. 
It’s used to validate a bank account and has two very large switch statements. I think I need to extract the logic inside the switch statements to a separate class. Each statement access different variables so I may need to make them more generalised first.

```
    @Override
    public BankDetailsValidationModel validate(String accountNumber, String sortCode) throws BankDetailsValidationException {
        final SimpleBankDetailsModel bankDetails = new SimpleBankDetailsModel(accountNumber, sortCode);
        final ModulusWeightTableEntry[] mwtEntries = getCopiesOfModulusWeightTableEntriesToUse(sortCode);

        if (mwtEntries.length > 0) {
            boolean checkPassed = false;
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            for (final ModulusWeightTableEntry entry : mwtEntries) {
                int expectedRemainder = 0;
                String dataToCheck = bankDetails.getSortCode() + bankDetails.getAccountNumber();
                boolean skipCurrentCheck = false;
                switch (entry.getExceptionRule()) {
                    case 1:
                        dataToCheck = "580149" + dataToCheck;
                        final int[] alternateDoublingForPrefix = new int[]{1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2};
                        entry.setWeights(ArrayUtils.addAll(alternateDoublingForPrefix, entry.getWeights()));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (bankDetails.charAt('a') != '0' && bankDetails.charAt('g') != '9') {
                            logDebugMessage("a != 0 and g !=9 so setting weights to 0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 3, 6, 4, 8, 7, 10, 9, 3, 1");
                            entry.setWeights(new int[]{0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 3, 6, 4, 8, 7, 10, 9, 3, 1});
                        } else if (bankDetails.charAt('a') != '0' && bankDetails.charAt('g') == '9') {
                            logDebugMessage("a != 0 and g == 9 so setting weights to 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 7, 10, 9, 3, 1");
                            entry.setWeights(new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 7, 10, 9, 3, 1});
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if ((bankDetails.charAt('c') == '6' || bankDetails.charAt('c') == '9') && entry.getAlgorithm().equals(DBLAL)) {
                            skipCurrentCheck = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        expectedRemainder = Integer.parseInt(bankDetails.substring('g', 'h'));
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        if (sortCodeInSubstitutionTable(bankDetails.getSortCode())) {
                            final String replaceWith = getSubstituteSortCode(bankDetails.getSortCode());
                            logDebugMessage(String.format("replacing sort code with %s for checking purposes", replaceWith));
                            dataToCheck = replaceWith + bankDetails.getAccountNumber();
                        } else {
                            logDebugMessage("exception case 5 but sort code not in substitution table");
                        }
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        if (ArrayUtils.indexOf(new char[]{'4', '5', '6', '7', '8'}, bankDetails.charAt('a')) != -1
                                && bankDetails.charAt('g') == bankDetails.charAt('h')) {
                            skipCurrentCheck = true;
                            checkPassed = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        if (bankDetails.charAt('g') == '9') {
                            entry.zeroise('u', 'b');
                        } else {
                            logDebugMessage(String.format("Exception case 7 but %s didn't meet condition for zeroise", bankDetails));
                        }
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        dataToCheck = "090126" + bankDetails.getAccountNumber();
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        if ((bankDetails.substring('a', 'b').equals("09") || bankDetails.substring('a', 'b').equals("99")) && bankDetails.charAt('g') == '9') {
                            entry.zeroise('u', 'b');
                        } else {
                            logDebugMessage(String.format("Exception case 10 but %s didn't meet criteria for zeroise", bankDetails));
                        }
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        break;
                    case 13:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                if (!skipCurrentCheck) {
                    final WeightedModulusCheck wmc = modulusChecksByAlgorithmName.get(entry.getAlgorithm());
                    switch (entry.getExceptionRule()) {
                        case 5:
                            final int remainder = wmc.getRemainder(dataToCheck, entry.getWeights());
                            if (entry.getAlgorithm().equals(MOD11)) {
                                if (bankDetails.charAt('g') == '0' && remainder == 0) {
                                    checkPassed = true;
                                } else if (remainder == 1) {
                                    checkPassed = false;
                                } else {
                                    checkPassed = (11 - remainder) == bankDetails.intAt('g');
                                }
                            } else if (entry.getAlgorithm().equals(DBLAL)) {
                                if (bankDetails.charAt('h') == '0' && remainder == 0) {
                                    checkPassed = true;
                                } else {
                                    checkPassed = (10 - remainder) == bankDetails.intAt('h');
                                }
                            } else {
                                logDebugMessage("Exception case 5 but could not find algorithm MOD11 or DBLAL");
                            }
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            checkPassed = wmc.check(dataToCheck, entry.getWeights(), expectedRemainder);
                            if (!checkPassed) {
                                logDebugMessage("retrying with sort code 309634");
                                dataToCheck = "309634" + bankDetails.getAccountNumber();
                                checkPassed = wmc.check(dataToCheck, entry.getWeights(), expectedRemainder);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 14:
                            checkPassed = wmc.check(dataToCheck, entry.getWeights(), expectedRemainder);
                            if (!checkPassed) {
                                final char digit8 = bankDetails.charAt('h');
                                if ('0' == digit8 || '1' == digit8 || '9' == digit8) {
                                    dataToCheck = bankDetails.getSortCode() + "0" +
                                    new StringBuilder(bankDetails.getAccountNumber()).deleteCharAt(7).toString();
                                    checkPassed = wmc.check(dataToCheck, entry.getWeights(), expectedRemainder);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            checkPassed = wmc.check(dataToCheck, entry.getWeights(), expectedRemainder);
                            break;
                    }
                    message.append(wmc.getName()).append(checkPassed ? " OK. " : " failed. ");
                    if (checkPassed) {
                        if (entry.remainingEntriesShouldBeSkipped()) {
                            break;
                        }
                    } else if (entry.failOnFirstFailure()) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return new BankDetailsValidationModel(checkPassed, true, message.toString().trim(), "");
        } else {
            return new BankDetailsValidationModel(true, false, "", "");
        }
    }
```

Comment: extract the switch statement out into it's own method. Then extract the logic on all the cases into it's own methods

Comment: Yikes.  Is it possible to the result of "getExceptionRule" with an enum? Or at the very least, add some well-named constants, instead of using magic numbers?

Comment: Yeah, the Enum isn't a bad idea. I'd like to move most the logic to another class, just trying to work out the best way to structure it.